# IE9 / IE10 Page Cannot Be Found

Tags: internet-explorer-9

This issue has occurred in the past week, and primarily with IE9, though I can occasionally
replicate it in IE10. Validators primarily tell me problems with NOWRAP and 
 so I will adjust those soon, but I have been unable to tell exactly what's causing "The webpage cannot be found", and the only common factor I can find from visitor feedback is IE9 and Windows 7.

URL: http://www.retroplanet.com

I did check everything else I could find in these forums, to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: You need to provide more information and context

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I'm not sure what else I can provide. When using IE9 to visit the web page directly at www.retroplanet.com the browser returns the default "The webpage cannot be found" alert, so shoppers cannot navigate the site. I've culled through the code and have been unable to determine exactly what IE9 is hating so much that it won't display the page to those users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens in IE 11 on windows 8.1 as well...  Opening Developer tools (F12), going to network, turning on network monitoring, then refresh, shows a 404 Result twice on the same component, `/horizontal/menuh/cssmenu.htc`

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! I appreciate your input. Now I'm off to determine where that file is and what it's doing...

Comment: .htc files are generally used for backward compatibility with older browsers, but they are depreciated in ie 8+... browsers other than ie tend to just ignore them.  I would start by searching in your .css files for references, as they are usually used for css hacks.

Comment: Hmm, found the reference in a css file and removed it. Tests through BrowserStack show good now, but locally on IE10, still "cannot be found" and Developer Tools still showing that the file is being searched for. Dumped cache, refreshed it all. Any more ideas? TIA!

Comment: worked for me after I cleared the browser history.  Perhaps you had an option unselected when you cleared your history?

Comment: I guess so. Just did it again and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help.  don't forget to accept the answer.  Nice site, by the way!

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. If I could, I'd vote it up! (noob here)